# How to get categories urls in the loop inside widget template?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, geturl

I have widget template like `app/design/frontend/ultimo/name/template/catalog/product/list_featured.phtml`

What's the way to **get category block urls** in first h3 like with products?

Source is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Featured Products
 */
?>
<?php
    $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
?>
<?php if ($_productCollection && ($_collectionSize = $this->getCollectionCount())): ?>

.../* PHP helpers */...

<div class="category-products">


<?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl($_category); ?>">
  <?php endforeach; ?>

<h3 class="section-title"><?php echo $this->getBlockName(); ?></h3>

<ul class="products-grid category-products-grid itemgrid itemgrid-adaptive itemgrid-6col centered hover-effect equal-height">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item">

            <div class="product-image-wrapper" style="max-width:<?php echo $imgWidth; ?>px;">

                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true); ?>" class="product-image">
                        <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                            src="<?php echo $helpImg->getImg($_product, $imgWidth, $imgHeight, 'small_image'); ?>"
                            alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true); ?>" />

                        <?php if ($theme->getCfg('category/alt_image')): ?>
                            <?php echo $theme->getAltImgHtml($_product, $imgWidth, $imgHeight); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php echo $helpLabels->getLabels($_product); //Product labels ?>
                    </a>

                    <?php //Add-to links
                        if ($gc['display_addtolinks'] != 0 && $gc['addtolinks_simple'])
                        {
                            if ($gc['display_addtolinks'] == 1) //Display on hover
                                echo $helpTemplate->getCategoryAddtoLinksIcons($_product, $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product), 'addto-links-icons addto-onimage display-onhover');
                            else //Always display
                                echo $helpTemplate->getCategoryAddtoLinksIcons($_product, $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product), 'addto-links-icons addto-onimage');
                        }
                    ?>

                </div> <!-- end: product-image-wrapper -->

            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h3>
            <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, $hash) ?>
            <div class="actions">
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>

                    <?php if ($this->getHideButton() == true): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php else: ?>

                    <?php if ($this->getHideButton() == false): ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php //Add-to links
                if ($theme->getCfg('category_grid/display_addtolinks') != 0 && !$theme->getCfg('category_grid/addtolinks_simple'))
                {
                    if ($theme->getCfg('category_grid/display_addtolinks') == 1) //Display on hover
                        echo $helpTemplate->getCategoryAddtoLinks($_product, $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product), 'addto-gaps-right addto-texticons display-onhover');
                    else //Always display
                        echo $helpTemplate->getCategoryAddtoLinks($_product, $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product), 'addto-gaps-right addto-texticons');
                }
                ?>
            </div>

        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul> <!-- end: itemslider-wrapper -->
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank I can use this widget with code like this in magento page editing:

```
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured.phtml" category_id="10"  id_path="category/10" product_count="12" breakpoints="[0, 1], [339, 2], [340, 3], [341, 2], [960, 4], [1280, 5]" timeout="5000" centered="1" size="size-m" hide_button="1"}}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your `$_categories` *is empty*

#### For example:

you can create a function in your block:

```
<?php 
public function getCategoriesListe(){
return Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection(); 
->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
}
?>
```

and call it from your template.

#### Example:

```
 $_categories = $this->getCategoriesListe() ;  
 foreach($_categories as $_category):
 echo $_category->getUrl();
 echo $_category->getName();

 endforeach;
```

Comment: Thank you!
But how can I refer to existed product collection in a loop ?

File template is http://jsbin.com/xerikenasu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Well I solved it just with 
 `<?php echo $this->getBlockUrl(); ?>`